# Does savechanges() exception in ef core rollback changes within a context?

Tags: database, .net-core, entity-framework-core

**Info**

I'm using ef core together with .net core 3.1 (code-first approach) and this is my first time using this framework.

**Scenario**

I want to commit some changes that I made to my entities to the database (simple add/remove/update operations). I'm using SaveChanges or SaveChangesAsync method (I do not manually operate on any transactions). Let's say something went wrong and I get an exception.

**Question**

From what I can understand no changes were made to the database, but what about the context? Let's say that I want to perform some other operation within try..catch block on those entities (e.g. try to save at least part of the changes made).

1. Do changes persist in the context after the exception was thrown on SaveChanges method?
2. When does the context refresh (per transaction, per request from user)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, your changes are saved and can be handled by catching DbUpdateException or DbUpdateConcurrencyException as an example.

For example:

```
            try
            {
                // Commit your operation
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException ex) when (ex.InnerException is SqlException sqlEx)
            {
                if (ex.Entries.Any())
                {
                    // entity framework knows about failed entities
                    foreach (var e in ex.Entries)
                    {
                       // Make necessary actions
                    }
                }
            }
```

2. Entity Framework has different states of entities handling. Adding an entity to a Context does not make any changes in your database. You will be able to see current changes in context.ChangeTracker.
   All changes will be released after transaction(SaveChanges or SaveChangeAsync).